# Unit: Resolve generic service using object type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

What i'm trying to accomplish is to have a single wcf service that has (for example) an Insert(ICommand command) method and can resolve a generic service that knows how to insert the underling object type.

Where's my (poor) attempt on a sandbox project.
Besides other flaws, this services allow to attempt to insert any ICommand.
I'm relative new Unit user and i was wondering if someone has a better way to accomplish this.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cmd = new SingleCommand();
            var cmd2 = new DoubleCommand();

            var s = new MyWcfService();
            s.Insert(cmd);
            s.Insert(cmd2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface ICommand { }
    public interface ICommandService
    {
        void Insert(ICommand command);
    }

    public interface ICommandService<in T> : ICommandService where T : ICommand
    {
        void Insert(T command);
    }

    public class SingleCommand : ICommand { }
    public class DoubleCommand : ICommand { }

    public class SingleCommandService : ICommandService<SingleCommand>
    {
        public void Insert(SingleCommand singleCommand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserted a SingleCommand");
        }

        void ICommandService.Insert(ICommand command)
        {
            Insert((SingleCommand)command);
        }
    }

    public class DoubleCommandService : ICommandService<DoubleCommand>
    {
        public void Insert(DoubleCommand doubleCommand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserted a DoubleCommand");
        }

        void ICommandService.Insert(ICommand command)
        {
            Insert((DoubleCommand)command);
        }
    }

    public static class Config
    {
        public static UnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();
        static Config()
        {
            Container.RegisterType<ICommandService, SingleCommandService>(typeof(SingleCommand).Name);
            Container.RegisterType<ICommandService, DoubleCommandService>(typeof(DoubleCommand).Name);
        }
    }

    public class MyWcfService
    {
        public void Insert(ICommand command)
        {
            var foo = Config.Container.Resolve<ICommandService>(command.GetType().Name);
            foo.Insert(command);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about or problem with what you've done?

Comment: Well, my question is how i can accomplish to "to have a single wcf service that has (for example) an Insert(ICommand command) method and can resolve a generic service that knows how to insert the underling object type" in a correct way. I updated my question to clarify the kind of help i'm looking for. thank you for the feedback

Comment: Prevent the ambiguity in your design by removing the `ICommand` and `ICommandService` methods. Take a look at [this inplementation](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't have a service that can be invoked for all `ICommand`, then you shouldn't offer that in its contract. An easy way around this is to extend the `ICommand` interface into something like `IServiceCommand`, and have those `ICommand` which are supported implement `IServiceCommand` instead, and tie your service contract instead to that interface. This allows your concrete classes to be used in any method which expects an `ICommand`, but your service still only service those `ICommand` which are also `IServiceCommand`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's already an interface named `ICommand` in `System.Windows.Input`, so you may want to avoid that name for clarity's sake.